# Database Design : How to save selected row

Tags: sql, database

I have a table to store the region in every **client** like this

```
{id, name, ....}
```

User can choose one of the region and I need to save it. Notice that only **one** region can be selected.

**SOLUTION 1:**
Add a new column called selected and add index based on this column.

So every time user select a region, I need to run two update SQL.

```
UPDATE table set selected = 0 where selected = 1
Update table set selected = 1 where id = xxx
```

When I need to retrieve the selected region, run the query

```
SELECT * from table where selected = 1
```

It works but seems not well designed. First of all, the space usage is not good as I add a new column. And the performance is not good too because every time I need to run two update query when user select another region.

**SOLUTION 2:**
If I open a new table to save the selected region id, it seems quite strange to have just one row in a table.

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT * from table where id = xxx` work?

Comment: Yes, but I need to store xxx somehow. Open a table just for store one xxx?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit user's table you could add a column for the selected region id an run only update on user's table based on users id.
If you cannot edit users table you will have to create another table with user's id and region's id and also update that table based on user's id.

The region Id in user's table would be a foregin key linking to the record in region table. If you have to create aditional table, that would be a compsite key linking records in user's table with records in region's table

Comment: Sorry, the db is in client side. Therefore I don't have a user table.

Comment: So you could go with the composite key. This is a standard concept for linking table in relational databases, but mostly is used to join tables in one to many relation ship. Using composite key, you only have to update one table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not reading your question correctly here.

But if you have a table for regions:
regionID - name

and a table for users:

userID - otherdata - regionID

Then if a user selects another regions, you only need to update the regionID in the user table no?

Or am I  missing some functionality?